# Composable don't clear previous state after object.observeAsState() changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I'm trying to implement a simple loading `CircularProgressIndicator()` while another data is being fetch. And when the data is ready, to set the correct compose content.

The code works fine at first, the loading indicator shows, then the data is ready and the Composable set the data on `OtherComposeContent()`. But the loading indicator `CircularProgressIndicator()` don't disappear and stay on the same UI has the new data.

I tried different implementation but no success.

```
val objectReady by objectViewModel.objectReady.observeAsState()
LaunchView(state = objectReady)

@Composable
fun LaunchView(state:Boolean?){
    if (state == true){
        OtherComposeContent() // New view when data is ready. Works fine
    } else {
        CircularProgressIndicator() // Loading circle while feetching data - Should dissapear when state is true but no
    }
```

Comment: I can't think of a reason why this view can not work. In my [sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/18ed14705521e8bc387167da85f1b9a9) without a view model it works fine. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://github.com/jaswinderwadali/mvvm-compose-hilt-sample use this sample

Answer (score 0):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class EntryPointActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val photosVM: PhotosViewModel by viewModels()
        setContent {
            RbotTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    if (photosVM.snapshotStateList.isEmpty()) {
                        LoadingState()
                    } else
                        MainContent(photosVM.snapshotStateList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoadingState(){
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
            Text(text = "Loading...", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
        }
}

@Composable
fun MainContent(photoList: SnapshotStateList<PhotosModel>) {
    Column {
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.weight(1f),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
        ) {
            items(
                items = photoList,
                itemContent = {
                    BasicCard(it)
                })
        }
    }

}
```

[Full Sample Code](https://github.com/jaswinderwadali/mvvm-compose-hilt-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/r/bot/ui/containers/EntryPointActivity.kt)

Comment: Does "val photosVM: PhotosViewModel by viewModels()" observe any changement to rebuild the compose view ?

Comment: SnapshotStateList is for the state management if something is changed in this object, it will re-render the state of the specific view.